# trac Upgrade from 0.10.3 to 0.12 debian server

Tags: trac

I´m trying to upgrade trac! from 0.10.3 to 0.12. Need help, i basiclally did steps shown here

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracUpgrade

got Linux version 2.6.18-6-686 (Debian 2.6.18.dfsg.1-18etch1) (waldi@debian.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)) #1 SMP Sun Feb 10 22:11:31 UTC 2008

got Python 2.4.4 (#2, Jan 24 2010, 11:19:18)
mysql: Server version: 5.0.32-Debian_7etch11-log Debian etch distribution

**So i went through this commands without errors:**

todasana:~# easy_install —upgrade Trac0.12 Searching for Trac0.12

---

todasana:~# trac-admin /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/trac_catw3 upgrade

---

todasana:~# trac-admin /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/trac_catw3 wiki upgrade

---

todasana:~# trac-admin /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/trac_catw3 repository resync ‘*’

---

*Didn´t do Step 5 Refresh static resources, because i did not understand it, and i think it does not apply to me: trac-admin /path/to/env deploy /deploy/path*

then i 
**restarted apache:
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart**

got this error in the browser now:
Mod_python error: "PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 299, in HandlerDispatch
    result = object(req)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/modpython_frontend.py", line 87, in handler
    gateway.run(dispatch_request)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/wsgi.py", line 87, in run
    response = application(self.environ, self._start_response)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/main.py", line 377, in dispatch_request
    env = _open_environment(env_path, run_once=run_once)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/main.py", line 58, in _open_environment
    env_cache[env_path] = open_environment(env_path)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/env.py", line 435, in open_environment
    if env.needs_upgrade():
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/env.py", line 315, in needs_upgrade
    if participant.environment_needs_upgrade(db):
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/env.py", line 373, in environment_needs_upgrade
    raise TracError, 'Database newer than Trac version'

**TracError: Database newer than Trac version**

Yesterday i fixed the error, how ever got a new one! And the way i
fixed the previous one i did not like, i think it was not really fixed
and i'm getting more errors because of it

I changed a value on the database: UPDATE `system` SET `value` = ‘19’.
(orginal value was 26)

Source control, and navigation work fine, however can´t create new
ticket! i get:

---

Oops…
Trac detected an internal error:

If you think this really should work and you can reproduce it, you
should consider reporting this problem to the Trac team.

Go to trac.edgewall.org and create a new ticket where you
describe the problem, how to reproduce it. Don't forget to include the
Python traceback found below.

TracGuide — The Trac User and Administration Guide
Python Traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/main.py", line 387,
in dispatch_request
    dispatcher.dispatch(req)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/main.py", line 237,
in dispatch
    resp = chosen_handler.process_request(req)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/ticket/web_ui.py", line
302, in process_request
    get_reporter_id(req, 'author'))
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/ticket/web_ui.py", line
658, in _insert_ticket_data
    actions = TicketSystem(self.env).get_available_actions(ticket,
req.perm)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/ticket/api.py", line
83, in get_available_actions
    return [action for action in actions.get(ticket['status'],
['leave'])
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/ticket/model.py", line
104, in **getitem**
    return self.values[name]
KeyError: 'status'

### "

HOW EVER, if i change the database system value to 20, i THE SITE
WORKS, however when i create a ticket i get the original error:

---

Mod_python error: "PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend"

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line
299, in HandlerDispatch
    result = object(req)

File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/
modpython_frontend.py", line 87, in handler
    gateway.run(dispatch_request)

File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/wsgi.py", line 87,
in run
    response = application(self.environ, self._start_response)

File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/main.py", line 377,
in dispatch_request
    env = _open_environment(env_path, run_once=run_once)

File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/web/main.py", line 58,
in _open_environment
    env_cache[env_path] = open_environment(env_path)

File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/env.py", line 435, in
open_environment
    if env.needs_upgrade():

File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/env.py", line 315, in
needs_upgrade
    if participant.environment_needs_upgrade(db):

File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/trac/env.py", line 373, in
environment_needs_upgrade
    raise TracError, 'Database newer than Trac version'

TracError: Database newer than Trac version

---

any ideas ? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to deploy a new environment of trac, move database (updated value of system to 19 as required) and config file, add another vhost for this instance and test again.

Comment: did all that before getting to this point, actually i created a new environment, i´m using the new database that is created when creating the environment, deleted the old vhost and added a new one, only change in config file was the addition to the svn path.

Comment: I would check dependencies: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall#Dependencies, Trac changed dependecies radically from version to version. Check sqlite dependecy. If you are ok with the dependencies, backup trac (egg file) and reinstall using "easy_install Trac"

Comment: So, I suggest a clean install for trac, test it empty and do changes in order to make it work, when it works migrate the db, config and reinstall plugins.

Comment: i guess its the only way! fresh start. Thank you Paul

Comment: I suggested a fresh install for trac and a migration of db and plugins to the new trac install.

Comment: I understand, how ever, since i was all old on everything on my server, and got everything all mixed up, i decided to install debian lenny, and re install everything migrating the data. it all worked fine! thank you Paul